# How to infer correctly the type of a merged array of object?

Tags: typescript

I have the following function:

```
function mergeArray<T extends Array<Record<string, any>>>(f: T) {
  return f.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
      ...curr,
    };
  }, {});
}

const e = mergeArray([{ foo: 1 }, { bar: "test" }, { baz: true }]);
// expected e type is { foo: number; bar: "test"; baz: boolean; }
```

How can I write the return type of the transform function so the type can be inferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but we can make sure to cast the return type and make it in such a way that it returns the intersection of the tuple elements.

1. We get the constituent Union types from the tuple/array
2. Convert the Union to Intersection type
3. Compute the intersection type to resolve to the object type

```
function mergeArray<T extends readonly any[]>(f: T): Compute<MergeArray<T>> {
  return f.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
      ...curr,
    };
  }, {});
}

const e = mergeArray([{ foo: 1 }, { bar: "test" }, { baz: true }] as const);
//   ^?


// Just to prettify the output and force TS to evaluate the intersection type 
type Compute<T> = { -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] } & unknown


type TupleToUnion<T extends readonly any[]> = T[number]

type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never;

type MergeArray<T extends readonly any[]> = UnionToIntersection<TupleToUnion<T>>
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwKYCcDmqCC70CGAngDwAqiqAHlKmACYDOi6qB9CANkYgWEQG0AugD4AFMABciMgEppAYTjIADiFokAshmx5CpMiJGIA3gChELVFBDokwAHSt6ICKjFiCECABpEEW3RZRABeY3NLS1YbO1MLSMsHJK9feISkhwD8HzTEAF8Abni8vxM82SK8szMIBEYoSlCUHVx8YjEBE0RgODhpAEZ80sQAIwJ0aQAiWnrJodNRggAvaSh0EFR8oV5mWrB6irMAeiPIgD0Afmrj04ApEHrEKDhEFWjYYB4oAAtNuHU1A0%20PRunB0G4ZABlJ4vVAANwInBABFoT1%20iBgYFo6EYqGg8CQUCIKk2ZiJJMQSlU6lQ5GMIQWAFpWOwuDwBABpDFIADWqCIcGAMiE0jInO2eUQADJEOAeWA4AB3MDXcmbMggFScVBkOAAVTABPIlBodCYVlZYG4vH4wnpMgEYBAyBGGCE1TViANBN1AEksRhcfiECQ9faxHqTbQGMw%20DwLogxDzpHrZGE4XAYCDpGB4RhgtRo%20aPMnucAMIhfWmRBms8EE77EDm8%20gimTiZttFhWvpjYWzcwWRwrTw43amt6EH6Azi8bAQxqtTr9YaF0ZqkA)